# Selenium WebDriver и несколько .get() в цикле

Tags: python, selenium, get

Ничего не понимаю.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe' )

for page in range(1,10):

    # получаем страницу каталога
    browser.get('https://www.site.net/go/' + str(page))

    # получаем все ссылки на из каталога
    items = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.items_all')

    # перебор всех ссылок
    for elem in items:

        # !при втором обходе ошибка, говорит что элемента нет
        href = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('div.hrefa a').get_attribute('href')

        # получаем страницу товара
        browser.get(href)

        # поулчаем заголовок
        title = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('h1.title').text

        #
        print(title)
```

Однако если не использовать повторный browser.get(href) то все хорошо, а если использую то ошибка, элемент не найден (stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document).

Получается что items - это ссылка и поэтому такая ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Для тех кто с такой траблой столкнулся, просто перебиваете найденные элементы методом find_elements_by_css_selector и добавляете в новый массив )